# Geopandas Installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, conda, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas on my Mac OS X right now.

**What I have done:**

• Downloaded and installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Graphical installer.

• `python --version` returns the following result: `Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)`

• Installed geopandas using this line : `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`. This command also, as I understand, installed all other required packages. Here's the list of all that command installed:

```
click-plugins:   1.0.3-py27_0       conda-forge
cligj:           0.4.0-py27_0       conda-forge
descartes:       1.1.0-py27_0       conda-forge
expat:           2.1.0-2            conda-forge
fiona:           1.7.3-np111py27_0  conda-forge
freexl:          1.0.2-1            conda-forge
gdal:            2.1.3-np111py27_0  conda-forge
geopandas:       0.2.1-py27_3       conda-forge
geos:            3.5.1-1            conda-forge
giflib:          5.1.4-0            conda-forge
hdf4:            4.2.12-0           conda-forge
json-c:          0.12-0             conda-forge
kealib:          1.4.6-3            conda-forge
libdap4:         3.18.3-2           conda-forge
libnetcdf:       4.4.1.1-2          conda-forge
libpq:           9.5.4-3            conda-forge
libspatialindex: 1.8.5-1            conda-forge
libspatialite:   4.3.0a-14          conda-forge
munch:           2.1.0-py27_0       conda-forge
openjpeg:        2.1.2-2            conda-forge
pcre:            8.39-0             conda-forge
proj4:           4.9.3-2            conda-forge
psycopg2:        2.6.2-py27_1       conda-forge
pyproj:          1.9.5.1-py27_0     conda-forge
pysal:           1.13.0-py27_0      conda-forge
rtree:           0.8.3-py27_0       conda-forge
shapely:         1.5.17-np111py27_2 conda-forge
xerces-c:        3.1.4-0
```

• geopandas appears when I run `conda list`

• I wrote some code in test.py:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gpd.read_file("osm_mexico_city/mexico-city_mexico_roads.geojson")
```

**The problem(s):**

• When I run execute `python test.py` in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
import geopandas as gpd
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from geopandas.io.file import read_file
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 3, in <module>
import fiona
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 9, in <module>
from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libgdal.20.dylib requires version 45.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 44.0.0
```

• Second way I tried is through PyCharm. I have set the project interpreter to python 2.7. There geopandas does not appear in the package list, therefore PyCharm blocks even before that:

```
    import geopandas as gpd
ImportError: No module named geopandas
```

Hope anyone has an idea of how to fix both.

**UPDATE 1**

After installing Anaconda `brew doctor` returns this now:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Anaconda is known to frequently break Homebrew builds, including Vim and
MacVim, due to bundling many duplicates of system and Homebrew-available
tools.

If you encounter a build failure please temporarily remove Anaconda
from your $PATH and attempt the build again prior to reporting the
failure to us. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  //anaconda/bin/curl-config
  //anaconda/bin/dap-config
  //anaconda/bin/freetype-config
  //anaconda/bin/gdal-config
  //anaconda/bin/geos-config
  //anaconda/bin/icu-config
  //anaconda/bin/kea-config
  //anaconda/bin/libpng-config
  //anaconda/bin/libpng16-config
  //anaconda/bin/nc-config
  //anaconda/bin/pcre-config
  //anaconda/bin/python-config
  //anaconda/bin/python2-config
  //anaconda/bin/python2.7-config
  //anaconda/bin/xml2-config
  //anaconda/bin/xslt-config
```

Seems related to this issue. How do I fix these to make my stuff work?

**UPDATE 2**

We can forget about the PyCharm problem, it turns out somehow I had another python 2.7 and this is the one he was suggesting. I've changed it to the Anaconda python 2.7 and now it gives the same error as the terminal output.

Comment: Pretty sure its the same fix for both

Comment: Well yeah they are somehow related. At least, if we solve the import error in PyCharm, I then expect it to give the same error as the terminal.

Comment: Wait, nvm. Are you saying that PyCharm does not use the version of Python installed on the local platform? Because conda, like pip, pretty much only installs for the interpreter it is bundled with.

Comment: I have only one python 2.7 so it should use the same. But maybe I have to link conda to PyCharm somehow also.

Comment: That is unlikely. I was thinking that PyCharm had it's own internal Python, but I suspect that's not true.

Comment: [This post](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/)  - although relevant to windows - really helped me understand when I was having issues. Might have some tips. Main tip I got from it - install dependencies first (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what happened with Anaconda, but it turns out the dependencies were not compatible.

```
conda install fiona=1.6
```

Downgrading Fiona to 1.6 solved everything for me.

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same problem, and finally solved this through this method:

1. First install geopandas using conda (This will install all dependencies)

   conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
2. Uninstall Fiona

   conda uninstall fiona
3. Download fiona wheel and install
   (I downloaded from here https://pypi.python.org/packages/71/ea/908bf078499b30d1ec374eb5baba016a568fc8142ee6ccf72e356d20871c/Fiona-1.7.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl#md5=971393c23ffc552664b7c694b992fb3e)

   pip install Fiona-1.7.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
4. Reinstall geopandas

   pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git

Comment: "I can fly higher than an eagle...but you are the wind beneath my wings."

Comment: I have a similar problem. do you have the download link for linux? Besides, is this issue still open? kind of annoying to work with outdated packages.

Comment: For up to date downloads for Fiona see: https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/#files (make sure you choose the right link for your version of Python - they are listed in reverse order). That said, I've not got the 4th step to work quite yet.